# What's up with the white knight in the forest of the lost giants?

Tags: dark-souls-2

Relatively early in the forest of the lost giants you climb up a ladder and there sits a white knight beneath a tree. He looks like an NPC, he does not attack or react in any way, but there is also no talk-prompt for me to use. What's up with this guy?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He is a Heide knight. There are several of them in the game and he won't attack you until you attack him. He's not a regular NPC and doesn't talk, but he is much stronger than the other enemies and if you kill him, you get a good weapon. As far as I know, they are just normal enemies and offer no other possibility of interaction but killing them.

Comment: Ah, okay. It felt just so unusual for a DS game to have someone who does not attack on sight, yet can't be spoken to.

Comment: They are different from normal enemies: They do not respawn and have scripted drops.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 in the game. All of them are non-hostile, unless provoked. Especially the one in Forest of Fallen Giants can prove a huge challenge to new players, because of its wide range and immense damage.

'They' are called [Heide Knights.](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Heide+Knight#.U21OJvl_uZw)
The first one you encounter will most likely be in the [Forest of Fallen Giants,](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Forest+of+Fallen+Giants#.U21YCfl_uZw) 2 more are found in [The Lost Bastille](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Lost+Bastille#.U21YRvl_uZw) and [Shrine of Winter](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Shrine+of+Winter#.U21YYPl_uZw).

In normal mode, they drop the weapons Heide Knight Sword, Heide Spear and Heide Lance.

If you play on [NG+](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/New+Game+Plus#.U21ZB_l_uZw) or use a [Bonfire Ascetic](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Bonfire+Ascetic#.U21Y7Pl_uZw), you will receive parts of the [Heide Knight Armour Set.](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Heide+Knight+Armor+Set#.U21ZYfl_uZw)